# Linear fitting with scipy.optimize

Tags: python, r, numpy

so I'm trying to make a linear fit of a function that I've previously transformed to loglog on both axes.

Transformed variable looks like, both variables are arrays.

```
years2 = years[:21]
plt.plot(np.log(years2), np.log(ntrees[:len(years2)]), '-g')
```

Code looks like this.

```
def rquared(y,y_fit):
    ss_res = np.sum((y - y_fit) ** 2) # Total squares res
    ss_tot = np.sum((y - np.mean(y)) ** 2) # Total squares
    return 1 - (ss_res / ss_tot)     # R^2

def ajuste_lineal(x,y):
  f = lambda x, a, b: a * x + b # linear function
  popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y) # without y uncertainty
  sigmas = np.sqrt([pcov[0,0],pcov[1,1]])
  a=popt[0]
  b=popt[1]
  ea=sigmas[0]
  eb=sigmas[1]
  R = rquared(y,a*x+b)
  print('R^2 = %0.2f' % R)
  print('Pendiente: %f ± %f'% (a,ea))
  print('Ordenada al origen: %f ± %f' % (b,eb))
  return a,b,ea,eb,R
```

When I run `a,b,ea,eb,R = ajuste_lineal(np.log(yearss2), np.log(ntrees[:len(years2)]))` this error pops up:

```
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Any suggestions?` - search using the error message and look through the results to get a feel for why this error occurs and possibly find a Q&A similar to your situation that you can adapt the answer.

Comment: You should provide a minimal example of the data and show your imports. Please read [mre]. When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)